# Can I restore a netbeans project from the .jar file?

Tags: netbeans, missing-data

Ack! I'm in a pickle here. An app developer friend of mine were both laid-off, when we came back and were trying to get projects up and running again one of our Projects in NetBeans won't work properly. I have the .jar file, but when I go in to re-load the project in NetBeans to makes some tweaks, the nbproject folder is totally missing (as you can see in the screen shot.)

This project hasn't been touched in at least two years and is housed on a Remote Computer, I can't just right click and restore a previous version. Is there another way to restore this project without having to totally rebuild it?

[image: Project Screen shot]

Be patient with me, I'm not all that experienced with these things. But, as you can see, the nbproject folder is just simply gone. I'd love to say when this happened, but I have no idea. I've tried to look for a previous version but there is no previous version on this remote computer. I've tried everything I can think of to restore the missing folder, now I'm trying to find out if there is a way to import the .jar and rebuild from that.

Comment: You need the Java source code to open (or import) a Java project in NetBeans (and other IDEs). So, what's in that `/src` folder shown in the screenshot? Failing that, there is a `/.git` folder also - so maybe you have full Git version history (of the source) in there. You need to use Git to open that.

Comment: Regarding the question in the title "_Can I restore a netbeans project from the .jar file?_", a JAR file is just a zip file. So unzip it and see what it contains. It may contain the source code, if you are lucky (if someone chose to add the source to the JAR - but probably they did not).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately the files were not included...but I was able to get our IT dept to restore the folder to a previous date where I could retrieve the files.